# MySQL Product filters by multiple attributes

Tags: mysql, filter

How get a products haves all requested attributes

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute` WHERE (`attribute_id`=15 AND `text`="2500") OR (`attribute_id`=18 AND `text`="24")
```

this request, returned following result:

```
|product_id | attribute_id | language_id | text
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----
|1          | 15           | 1           | 2500
|2          | 15           | 1           | 2500
|3          | 15           | 1           | 2500
|4          | 15           | 1           | 2500
|3          | 18           | 1           | 24  
|4          | 18           | 1           | 24
```

but I need only product 3 and 4, because they have 15=2500 and 18=24. How I do it?

Comment: You already know how to use the `WHERE` clause, but you don't know how to add a filter for `product_id`?

Comment: @Tom And what filter would that be?

Comment: @Strawberry, this is product attributes table, and I get filtred products by returned product id. My question not exactly to understand. But in any case, thanks for the help. I reached desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id 
  FROM oc_product_attribute
 WHERE (attribute_id,text) IN ((15,'2500'),(18,'24')) 
 GROUP 
    BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id,text) = 2;
```

I have a feeling that this shorthand negates the use of indexes, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: if first line `SELECT DISTINCT product_id AS product_id` and last line `HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 2` this seems to work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, you've not shown us your schema/data set, so only you can know

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple conditions and return value matching all the condition here is a way to do it

```
select p1.* from oc_product_attribute p1
where 
p1.`attribute_id`=15 AND p1.`text`='2500'
and exists
(
  select 1 from oc_product_attribute p2
  where
  p2.attribute_id = 18 
  and p2.text = 24
  and p1.product_id = p2.product_id
)
union all
select p1.* from oc_product_attribute p1
where 
p1.`attribute_id`=18 AND p1.`text`='24'
and exists
(
  select 1 from oc_product_attribute p2
  where
  p2.attribute_id = 15 
  and p2.text = 2500
  and p1.product_id = p2.product_id
)
;
```

Comment: Good, Is it possible to to perform such a request whis DISTINCT by product_id?

Comment: well distinct will only return one product out of each criteria.